# changing MapFragment height through code

Tags: android, google-maps, mapfragment

Is there any way to change the MapFragment height through code ?Please see the Layout file.
    `

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/feedList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@color/DarkGray"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

`

I had a header view for the ListView(Shown in the FrameLayout) and adding that through code. When the user clicks on the header view i want to make the MapFragment height to MatchParent. I hope you got the question and if you need any clarification please comment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the map fragment(list also) as framelayout as well and replace with your fragment in your code, otherwise you can not change the size of the fragment, it will be static.